# asp.net create xlsx and pdf files

Tags: asp.net, pdf, xlsx

I have an intranet web site based app, where I want to do the following:

When a user presses the button, a server-side xlsx template gets filled in with the relevant data from the back-end table and then the file is saved as both xlsx and pdf format. 
The reason to save xlsx is to (maybe) make it easier to save as pdf. The pdf version will then be emailed to the user for review.

I **cannot** use external libraries, so need to do it all from scratch.

Given that, MSFT does not recommend using office automation libraries, what would be the best approach? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I understand that this is a broad question, but I am looking for ideas and suggestions. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: I don't think there's a native capability in .NET for generating PDF files - I've only seen external 3rd party libraries for that.

Comment: This maybe a newbie thing, but when I am in Excel I can save as pdf, so I wonder if I could use  that feature. The server does have both Excel and Adobe Pro installed.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to use any of the MS Office products to generate the PDF on the server - be it Excel or Word. From my personal experience, the Excel and Word processes start not shutting down and stay in memory forever and cause all sorts of havoc.

Comment: So then I guess I can fill in the template on the server-side, save it as an xlsx file with a different name and then send it to the client. And also user Adobe's APIs to create a pdf file?

Answer (score 0):

To generate XLSX from a web application, you do not need an XL library. Just generate a table. But, before that, set the content type of the output to a spreadsheet mime type.

```
Response.buffer=true
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.xls"
```

The browser will download the file as an XL and most spreadsheet programs will process it as a spreadsheet file without any problem.

However, PDFs cannot be generated without a library. 
http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=288&t=Can_I_create_and_edit_PDFs_without_using_a_third_party_PDF_library

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is using [ReportViewer Local control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms251671.aspx) to create a report that could easily exported as XLS or PDF. You could also use its [Render method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251839%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do it programmatically.